# How to access secure soap web service basic authentication in Windows Phone 7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, basic-authentication

1. I created a web service
   "http://service.mydomain.com/MobileService.asmx"
2. I created a Windows mobile application
3. I added a reference to this web service
4. I started coding and finished the WP7 application and deployed the we service
5. Then I used IIS 7.5 to disable anonymous authentication and used basic authentication to secure my web service.
6. After using basic authentication I added the new reference to my service and VS 2010 ask about authentication, I used my Username and Password
7. Then when I tried to use the new services I had an Exception.


   **Error on Reference.cs:**

   public System.IAsyncResult BeginGetArticle(MyWP7App.MyService.GetArticleRequest request, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {
                   object[] _args = new object[1];
                   _args[0] = request;
                   System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("GetArticle", _args, callback, asyncState);
                   return _result;
               }

CommunicationException: {"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}

StatusDescription: Unauthorized

```
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

This how I'm trying to connect to my web service:

in ParsingHelper.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    namespace MyWP7App
    {
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Categories
    {
        [XmlArray("Categories")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Category")]
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Collection { get; set; }
    }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("SubCategories")]
        public int SubCategoriesCount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("SubCategories")]
        [XmlArrayItem("SubCategory")]
        public ObservableCollection<SubCategory> Collection { get; set; }
    }
```

in MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

    namespace MyWP7App
    {
        public partial class CategoriesPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
        private ObservableCollection<Category> itemsSource;
        public ObservableCollection<Category> ItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsSource;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsSource = value;
            }
        }

        private static MyService.MobileServiceSoapClient Service = null;


        public PanoramaMainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (null == ItemsSource)
                GetCategories();
            else
                imtListBox.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;
        }

        private void GetCategories()
        {
            Service = new MyService.MobileServiceSoapClient();

            // I tried to do the following when the service is secure, but I had the same error:
            // Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
            // Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";

            Service.GetCategoriesCompleted += new EventHandler<MyService.GetCategoriesCompletedEventArgs>(Service_GetCategoriesCompleted);
            Service.GetCategoriesAsync();
        }
        void Service_GetCategoriesCompleted(object sender, MyService.GetCategoriesCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
                }
                if (!e.Cancelled)
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Categories));
                    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + e.Result.ToString() + "</root>");
                    Categories arts = new Categories();
                    arts = (Categories)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                    this.ItemsSourceListBox = arts.Collection;
                    imtListBox.ItemsSource = this.Items1Source;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            Service.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this post 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637320(VS.96).aspx

This post details how to pass username / password. Here's a snippet from the page

```
using (OperationContextScope contextScope = new OperationContextScope(svc.InnerChannel))
{
    byte[] bc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"username" + ":" + "password"); // the string passed after basic:
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpProps = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpProps.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(bc);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpProps;
    // call the service.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm adding the following: `svc.GetArticlesByCategoryIDCompleted += new EventHandler<MySRV.GetArticlesByCategoryIDCompletedEventArgs>(Completed);
svc.GetCategoriesAsync();` after the "// call the service." comment, but nothing happen even on debugging I cannot see any result out of GetArticlesByCategoryIDCompleted

Comment: Thanks @HermitDave, I was doing something wrong, it's now working fine :)

Comment: I'm sorry @HermitDave but I discover that I'm using my testing service URL instead of the secure one and it work fine, but whenever I try to use the deployed secure service I'm getting the same error .. sorry I was thinking that your solution is working but its not :(

Comment: Note: I'm using SOAP service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996507.aspx#webservbasics_topic2) I created a ASP.NET 3.5 webservices then upgraded the solution to 4.0, I'm not using a WCF service, is this why I'm getting this error "CommunicationException"?

Comment: I not sure what you need to do. create a post on app hub (might help) and specify that it works for http but not for https